# HTML + CSS circle with text around

Tags: html, css

Would it be possible to create this circle with HTML and CSS?
[image: circle with white background, blue border with text inside and around]

I could use svg, but I'm thinking I can't create text around it.

Comment: you can absolutely put text around an SVG http://codepen.io/SaraSoueidan/pen/ebfc92e45e24b29c266f50e6f617cdf5

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-text-along-arc-path/

Comment: @LeoFarmer you do not need to use canvas for this.

Comment: This is more like a google question: https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=css+wrap+text+around+circle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:: http://jsfiddle.net/t7rjj1hn/

```
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <defs>
        <path id="text_0_path" d="M 100 150 A 100 100 0 1 1 300 150"/>
    </defs>
    <use xlink:href="#text_0_path" stroke="blue" fill="none"/>
    <g font-family="Arial" font-size="18px">
        <text text-anchor="middle">
            <textPath xlink:href="#text_0_path" startOffset="50%">Test Text</textPath>
        </text>

    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Nice (though an arc isn't a circle). How browser-friendly is this?